# Link domain to dedicated server

Tags: apache, dns, ip, dedicated-server

I need some help, I can not find my answers, certainly because I am not asking my self the right questions. So here's the thing, in my very own home, in the very own room I'm writing this I got a dedicated machine running apache server. As well I bought the cheapest domain name I could find in order to make some experiments. But I can not seem to point my domain to my dedicated server. I don't understand how to do it. I suppose it important to say that my ISP uses dynamic IP addresses. Could someone point me toward some documentation please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are talking about your very own home, than you are talking about sitting behind a NAT. Thats means, that your router/gateway has to forward Port 80 to your apache server.

Moreover, you have to use a dynamic DNS solution (dyn.org, no-ip.com, ...) to link a domain to your dynamic ip address.

However, it is not possible to link a generic domain to a dynamic ip address.